# Javascript (localstorage) only one value gets stored. How can I store everything?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm getting user data from an open API, I store it the localstorage, I can display all the data but only the first value is getting saved in the localstorage. How can I store all the data?

My code :

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

function append(parent, element ) {
  return parent.appendChild(element);
}

const ul = document.getElementById('authors');
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';

fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {

    let authors = data.results;

    return authors.map(function(author) {

      const myObj = {
        name: `${author.name.first}`,
        lastname : `${author.name.last}`,
        email : `${author.email}`,
        location : `${author.location.city}, ${author.location.street}`,
        phone : `${author.phone}`
      }

      let li = createNode('li'),
          img = createNode('img'),
          span = createNode('span');

      let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);

      localStorage.setItem("myObj" , myObj_serialized);

      let myObj_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myObj"));

      document.getElementById('authors').innerHTML += 
        myObj_deserialized.name.capitalize() +  " " + 
        myObj_deserialized.lastname.capitalize() + " --- " + 
        myObj_deserialized.email + " --- " + 
        myObj_deserialized.location.capitalize() + " --- " + 
        myObj_deserialized.phone + "<br/> " ;

      console.log(myObj);    
    })
  })

  .catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   });
```

results :

[image]

And here we see only 1 value gets stored instead of 10.

[image]

Comment: Simply use `localStorage.setItems('authors', data.results)` after the API call, and delete the subsequents calls to `localStorage.setItem`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overriding the same object every time in localstorage, so at the end of your `map` the localstorage item `myObj` is set to the last item from the authors array. I would suggest using something unique, like the user's `email`, and set that in the localstorage.

```
  localStorage.setItem(author.email , myObj_serialized);

  let myObj_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(author.email));
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

As you are storing the data inside your `map` function, you are overwriting the object key `myObj` for every loop iteration.

you can notice that only the last object is in the `LocalStorage`.

You should store the entire response payload instead

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('authors');
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';
fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let authors = data.results;

    let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(authors);

    localStorage.setItem("myObj", myObj_serialized);

    // ... Everything else here
    // Now you should adapt your code.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) got it figured out

Answer (score 1):

Localstorage is a Map.
So by calling `setItem(key, value)` you override the value.
You can either use multiple keys or create an array and save the whole array.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) got it figured out

Answer (score 1):

** Basic concept map() Methods:**

1. map() creates a new array with the results of calling a function
   for every array element.
2. This method calls provided function  once for each element in an array in order.
3. Array elements without values does not execute.
4. Original array not change.

```js
return authors.map(function(author,index, arr) {

      const myObj = {
        name: `${author.name.first}`,
        lastname : `${author.name.last}`,
        email : `${author.email}`,
        location : `${author.location.city}, ${author.location.street}`,
        phone : `${author.phone}`
      }

      let li = createNode('li'),
          img = createNode('img'),
          span = createNode('span');

          let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);

          localStorage.setItem(index , myObj_serialized);

          let myObj_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(index));

          document.getElementById('authors').innerHTML += myObj_deserialized.name.capitalize() +  " " + myObj_deserialized.lastname.capitalize() + " --- " + myObj_deserialized.email + " --- " + myObj_deserialized.location.capitalize() + " --- " + myObj_deserialized.phone + "<br/> " ;

     

    })
```

**OR**

```js
let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);

          localStorage.setItem(myObj.phone , myObj_serialized);

          let myObj_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(myObj.phone));
```

**OR**

```js
  let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);

          localStorage.setItem(myObj.email , myObj_serialized);

          let myObj_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(myObj.email));
```